# Convert FastSet to Array of String

Tags: java

I have a set:
`Set<String> tmpSet = FastSet.newInstance();`

When i follow this question: [How to convert Set to String[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982447/how-to-convert-setstring-to-string)

and i do the same:
`String[] strArrStrings = includeFeatureIds.toArray(new String[0]);`

and i have this exception:

```
Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Message: Error running script at location [component://order/webapp/ordermgr/WEB-INF/actions/entry/catalog/KeywordSearch.groovy]: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Destination array too small
---- cause ---------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
Message: Destination array too small
---- stack trace ---------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Destination array too small
javolution.util.FastCollection.toArray(FastCollection.java:351)
```

So now, i have to code as:

```
for (FastSet.Record r = tmpSet.head(), end = tmpSet.tail(); (r = r.getNext()) != end;) {
         // copy one by one element to String[]  
     }
```

My question: Is there anyway(or utility) to convert FastSet to String[]?

Thank :-)

**See also:**

- [FastSet](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/util/FastSet.html)

Comment: @Pshemo That's so simple, i'm so bad, thank!

Comment: No problem. Since you have correct answer now I will remove my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [FastCollection#toArray(T[])](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/util/FastCollection.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29)

> Unlike standard Collection, this method does not try to resize the array

so you have to make the array the right size. Use

```
includeFeatureIds.toArray(new String[includeFeatureIds.size()])
```

instead of

```
includeFeatureIds.toArray(new String[0])
```

Comment: Thank for your answer and info inside it, i will mark as answer in 5 minutes :-)